# json encoding € symbol

Tags: php, mysql, json, utf-8

I have a php page generating json extracting values from a mysql table.
Everything is fine except where I have values containing euro symbol (like "€ 20,00") the euro symbol show up in my json as \u20ac...

Like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "535",
    "Name": "Pluto",
    "fare": "\u20ac 20,00"
  }
]
```

In the page evaluating this json it appears as "€ 20,00", so this is fine, but I really would like it to appear the same also in the json string itself.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multibyte can - as long as they are not control characters - be displayed literally or escaped as `\uXXXX` and both representations are correct. If you prefer the literally representation and if you use php to create the json then you need to pass the correct options to [`json_encode: Parameters`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-parameters)

The option you are looking for is [JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-unescaped-unicode):

> Encode multibyte Unicode characters literally (default is to escape as \uXXXX). Available since PHP 5.4.0

Comment: Great! Concise and to the point :-) 
I was yet using JSON_PRETTY_PRINT option, I didn't know how to combine this two together .. Discovered the correct way is like this:

json_encode($myArr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Just saying in case anyone else look at this.

Answer (score 2):

this is a very simple example.
I can complete it when i know what do you want exactly.

```js
var json = [
  {
    "id": "535",
    "Name": "Pluto",
    "fare": "\u20ac 20,00"
  }
];

$(function(){$('#screen').html(json[0].fare);});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='screen'></div>
```

this example is more perfect:
https://jsfiddle.net/a3dmorteza/x7fwto5L/

Comment: My problem wasn't with parsing and showing the value.
Since one of the strong point of json is to be human readable I just prefer euro symbol be inserted in my json data as literal and not escaped.
Anyway thank for your reply, your way of parsing the json gave me an hint for something else :-)

Comment: I now understand your problem and I think the @t.niese 's answer is the best answer.