# Json encode Unicode Symbol in PHP array

Tags: php, json, unicode

Given the following array

```
$locationIcon = array(
    'face' => 'FontAwesome',
    'code' => '\uf015',
    'size' => 75,
    'color' => 'gray',
);
```

which is encoded via `json_encode`, I would like to have this output:

```
{
    face: 'FontAwesome',
    code: '\uf015',
    size: 75,
    color: 'gray'
}
```

but instead I get these results:

#### Version 1

```
json_encode($array)
=>
"icon":{"face":"FontAwesome","code":"\\uf2bd","size":40,"color":"gray"}
```

#### Version 2 as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37372524/1092632)

```
json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
=> 
"icon" {"face":"FontAwesome","code":"\\uf2bd","size":40,"color":"gray"} (same)
```

#### Version 3 (add an escape char)

```
$locationIcon = array(
    'face' => 'FontAwesome',
    'code' => sprintf('%cuf2bd', 27),
    'size' => 100,
    'color' => 'gray',
);
json_encode($array)
=> 
"icon" {"face":"FontAwesome","code":"\u001buf233","size":40,"color":"gray"}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you have written the string "backslash u f zero one five", and JSON-encoding that preserves it exactly with that meaning. There's no sane way around that. Write the actual character you want, not "\uf015".

Comment: While I understand what you mean, how would I write the "actual" character of a FontAwesome Icon?

Comment: Do you want to serialize instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have written the string "backslash u f zero one five", and JSON-encoding that preserves it exactly with that meaning. There's no sane way around that. Write the actual character you want, not "\uf015". Since this particular character can be slightly awkward to write, write it in some alternative notation, like raw UTF-8 bytes:

```
$locationIcon = [
    'code' => "\xEF\x80\x95",  // U+F015
    ...
];

echo json_encode($locationIcon);  // {"code": "\uf015", ...}
```

Comment: thanks this works, but how did you convert `\uf015` to `\xEF\x80\x95`?

Comment: I looked it up in a Unicode table. If you want to do it in pure PHP, `echo bin2hex(json_decode('"\uf015"'));` would help.

Comment: Of course, Unicode escape notation in PHP 7 will do too: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double